# php set session with cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  
setcookie('user_id', '$login' , time()+86000);
header('Location: userindex.php');

function logged_in() {
return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) ? true : false;
}
```

I have SESSION but I wonna include COOKIE too but I don't know how to restart SESSION with COOKIE. I don't have a idea how I can get that. I create COOKIE but can't logout and have problem with SESSION somebody can help me to fix my problem???? And in every page on top I have logged_in function for check if user is logged in or not I wonna these logged_in function to check if user has cookie to auto login to user cookie. I think it is in logged_in function must get write some code and...

Comment: Please try to write in proper English.

Comment: I want to set SESSION with COOKIE. I had SESSION  How can I include COOKIE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will note that this is not secure, as any one can create the cookie, using something like firebug.

```
@session_start();

function logged_in() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    }
    return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
}

function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    setcookie("user_id", "", time() - 3600);
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    exit;
}
```

Edit: Added logout() - will remove both session and cookie 'user_id', then redirect to homepage

Comment: that is man how I can logout from COOKIE? can you help me to do it secure?

Comment: setcookie('user_id', $login, time()-86000); logout is that

Comment: I have problem when I close browser and restart the browser it is not reloaded a page

Comment: Are you using passwords for this login system? This function should set the session['user_id'] variable from the cookie that was set, after you restart the browser

Comment: $login = login($username, $password); In $login variable is function for check username and password combination

Comment: What would be a better idea is too  use `session_set_cookie_params` to set a far-future time that will ensure the session is not lost when you re-open the browser. No addional cookie would be needed http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: I got it thanks so much that is























 <a href=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2EWmx7HvC4 >youtube download</a>

Answer (score 1):

First: you should set it with:

```
setcookie('user_id', $login , time()+86000);
```

So $login without quotes. And also maybe set path variable if this cookie should be seen in different pages.

Removing cookie is done with setting negative time value:

```
setcookie('user_id', '' , time()-86000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

function logged_in() {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    }

    return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) && isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])));
}
```